# How to resolve this exception Could not access term breeze in package <root>

Tags: scala, maven

packing a project in java and scala with maven，then i get errors :

```
[ERROR] error: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Vectors.class'.
[INFO] Could not access term breeze in package <root>,
[INFO] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[INFO] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[INFO] A full rebuild may help if 'Vectors.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <root>
```

maven version 3.2.5

pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
     <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
  
<configuration>
   <scalaVersion>2.11.8</scalaVersion>
  </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Didn't you forget about adding breeze as dependency to your project https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze#maven ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @michaJlS

it's solved  when I added below dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalanlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>breeze_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```